# why does this code don't work in the content-editor? (MyTasks)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I wrote a JavaScript function where I get my Tasks and Tasks from Team Space. They are supposed to look like: [image]

And this works as long as its a own HTML-site. Like tasks.html. When I try to add it to another SharePoint-site like home in an content-Editor I get an typeerror:

> sp.ui.utility is undefined

and the site stops responding. So my question is why is that so? There is something I don't get.

Here is the Code:
HTML:

```
<div class="due-display" id="dueDisplayVisibility" onclick="winOpen();">
    <p id="loadingText" class="loadIndicator">Loading...  <img src="/Style Library/kcs/images/loader.gif"></p>
    <div class="overDue" id="overDueForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-due-digits-red" id="overDueDigits"></th> <!--gets filled by function: fillDueDisplayForms()-->
                <th class="th-due-text-red" id="overDueText"></th> <!--gets filled by function: fillDueDisplayForms()-->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="dueSoon" id="dueSoonForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-due-digits-orange" id="dueSoonDigits"></th> <!--gets filled by function: fillDueDisplayForms()-->
                <th class="th-due-text-orange" id="dueSoonText"></th> <!--gets filled by function: fillDueDisplayForms()-->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="neverDue" id="neverDueForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="th-due-digits-green" id="neverDueDigits"></th> <!--gets filled by function: fillDueDisplayForms()-->
                <th class="th-due-text-green" id="neverDueText"></th> <!--gets filled by function: fillDueDisplayForms()-->
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="noMySite" id="noMySiteForm">
        <p id="noMySiteTextLine1" class="noMySiteText"></p> <!--gets filled by function: fillNoMySiteForm() -->
        <p id="noMySiteTextLine2" class="noMySiteText"></p> <!--gets filled by function: fillNoMySiteForm() -->
    </div>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.workmanagement.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Style%20Library/kcs/js/jquery.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    getMyTasks();
});
```

If you want I can post the full java script file.

Any help or advise would be great.

Edit:
Just tried it with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getMyTasks, "sp.js");
});
```

and the error stays the same: `sp.ui.utility is undefined`

Edit2: error was this line:

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

real name of the file:

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

together with the solution from below it works without any Problems.

Comment: Please tag your SharePoint version

Comment: made an edit sorry

Comment: It seems that your SP.js is not loaded.

Comment: Are you trying to put the HTML & JavaScript directly into the Content Editor?

Comment: @AmalHashim no with link from the file.

Comment: Do you have MDS activated on the Home Site

Comment: @AmalHashim mds is not active.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this for calling your function:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext',getMyTasks);
```

You will get more info from below link:

[SP.SOD.executeFunc(key, functionName, fn) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: wont work error stays the same `sp.ui.utility is undefined`. but at least the Browser no longer crashes.

Comment: Please try this...I've updated my answer

Comment: now it works but not fluid it laggs and loads very long. Sadly and as soon as i click somewhere on the site i get an error becouse `sp.ui.utility` is undefined.

Comment: turns out the error was `<script src="/_layouts/15/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` becouse the real name is `sp.init.js` and together with your code snippet it works. Thanks